# How To Run This Array As Foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays

How To Run Loop In PHP I Cant Do This i get error unknow object help me To Get data From This Array Code.

```
 Array
    (
        [invoice] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 76
                        [userid] => 18
                        [firstname] => Arshad
                        [lastname] => Shaik
                        [companyname] => Arshad Shaik
                        [invoicenum] => 
                        [date] => 2022-02-13
                        [duedate] => 2022-02-27
                        [datepaid] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [last_capture_attempt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [date_refunded] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [date_cancelled] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [subtotal] => 53.90
                        [credit] => 0.00
                        [tax] => 0.00
                        [tax2] => 0.00
                        [total] => 53.90
                        [taxrate] => 0.000
                        [taxrate2] => 0.000
                        [status] => Unpaid
                        [paymentmethod] => paytm
                        [paymethodid] => 
                        [notes] => 
                        [created_at] => 2022-02-13 09:00:04
                        [updated_at] => 2022-03-04 09:00:15
                        [currencycode] => INR
                        [currencyprefix] => ₹
                        [currencysuffix] => INR
                    )
    
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 106
                        [userid] => 18
                        [firstname] => Arshad
                        [lastname] => Shaik
                        [companyname] => Arshad Shaik
                        [invoicenum] => 
                        [date] => 2022-03-11
                        [duedate] => 2022-03-25
                        [datepaid] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [last_capture_attempt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [date_refunded] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [date_cancelled] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [subtotal] => 53.90
                        [credit] => 0.00
                        [tax] => 0.00
                        [tax2] => 0.00
                        [total] => 53.90
                        [taxrate] => 0.000
                        [taxrate2] => 0.000
                        [status] => Unpaid
                        [paymentmethod] => paytm
                        [paymethodid] => 
                        [notes] => 
                        [created_at] => 2022-03-11 09:00:13
                        [updated_at] => 2022-03-30 09:00:12
                        [currencycode] => INR
                        [currencyprefix] => ₹
                        [currencysuffix] => INR
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

I am trying Full Day But I Cant Get Data From This Array , Anyone Please Help Me To Do This work . i want to send sms using foreach loop using this array . Help to do this  am trying Full Day But I Cant Get Data From This Array , Anyone Please Help Me To Do This work . i want to send sms using foreach loop using this array . Help to do this

Comment: `foreach($array['invoice'] as $singleArray){ echo $singleArray['id']; // example }` ??

Comment: _"I Cant Do This i get error unknow object"_ - Please show us your attempt, expected output and the full error message you get.

Comment: You should also refrain from capitalizing the first letter of each word when you write your question. It doesn't only make it look unprofessional, but it also makes the text much harder to read.

Comment: "i want to send sms using foreach loop using this array" ... there are no phone numbers in the array, so who are you *sms* to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through `$array`'s `invoice` element. From there, each element of the array can be accessed as `$item` and `$item`'s elements can be accessed the same way you'd do with any other array.

```
$array = [
    'invoice' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 76,
            'userid' => 18,
            'firstname' => 'Arshad',
            'lastname' => 'Shaik',
            ...
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($array['invoice'] as $item) {
    echo 'item\'s id is ' . $item['id'] . '<br>';
    echo 'item\'s userid is ' . $item['userid'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Each element can be accessed without iterating.

Comment: That's perfectly true, but he was asking for how to iterate through $array's 'invoice' element

Comment: I agree with you, i havent had coffee yet